# Google Mock and protected copy constructor

Tags: constructor, copy, protected, googlemock

I have a class with a protected copy constructor:

```
class ThingList
{
public:
    ThingList() {}
    virtual ~ThingList() {}

    std::vector<Thing> things;

protected:
    ThingList(const ThingList &copy) {}
};
```

I have another class the uses this one:

```
class AnotherThing
{
public:
    AnotherThing()
    {
    }

    virtual ~AnotherThing() {}

    void DoListThing(const ThingList &list)
    {
    }
};
```

and a Mock version of this class:

```
class MockAnotherThing : public AnotherThing
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(DoListThing, void(const ThingList &list));
};
```

I want to call this method DoListThing with a real argument to supply a real list:

```
TEST(Thing, DoSomeThingList)
{
    MockThing thing;
    ThingList list;
    MockAnotherThing anotherThing;

    list.things.push_back(Thing());

    EXPECT_CALL(anotherThing, DoListThing(list));

    anotherThing.DoListThing(list);
}
```

I get an error compiling this:

```
1>..\mockit\googletest\googlemock\include\gmock\gmock-matchers.h(3746): error C2248: 'ThingList::ThingList': cannot access protected member declared in class 'ThingList'
```

Yet if I make a non-Mock call it works just fine:

```
ThingList list;
AnotherThing theRealThing;
theRealThing.DoListThing(list);
```

If in the Mock test I call with '_', it works:

```
TEST(Thing, DoSomeThingList)
{
    MockThing thing;
    ThingList list;
    MockAnotherThing anotherThing;

    list.things.push_back(Thing());

    EXPECT_CALL(anotherThing, DoListThing(_));

    anotherThing.DoListThing(list);
}
```

However, how can I pass a list in this case? If the list was returned by DoListThing, I could use Return but what do I for an argument that get modified like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to get past a protected copy constructor so my answer was to create a fake (dummy) version of a class and ignore Google Mock. This worked well enough for me to test the class in question. The example I provided here is a simplified version of the bigger package.